# Joining and aggregating data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

In customer table there is a `SupportID` which is the `WorkerId` in the worker Table, each `WorkerId` shows which will handle that customer.

```
Working Name | No. of accounts | total revenue 
----------------------------------------------
John McCoy     20                10,000
```

- Worker table contains - Firstname, Lastname, EmployeeId
- Receipt table contains - receipt Id, CustomerId,
- ReceiptLine Table contains - receiptlineId, receipt Id, Unitprice, quantity

At the moment I have this code / idea

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Employee A, Invoice B
WHERE A.EmployeeId = B.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 1):

In this question, you have not mention dependency among worker and receipt table. However, let the dependency column is workerId on table receipt. Now try this, hope you will get your desired result.

```
select a.firstName, sum(count(b.customerId)) as no_accounts, sum(c.unitPrice *c.quantity) as total_revenue 
from (( worker a join receipt b on a.workerId = b.SupportId) 
join receiptLine c on b.receiptId = c.receiptId) group by a.firstName order by a.firstName;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error >>> near "JOIN": syntax error:

Comment: In the above code "(" was missing,  now it's fine, try once again.

Comment: did you take this into consideration >>> In customer table there is a SupportID which is the WorkerId in the worker Table, each workerId shows which will handle that customer.

Comment: This piece of code is fairly correct just modify column and table name, coding pattern is perfect here.

Comment: when you do sum(count) its saying misuse of aggregate function

Comment: b.SupportId won't work because supportId is inside customer table Not Invoice Table

Comment: @ Arif Sarker Is there a way to do it using a sub query

Comment: In Receipt table you have to declare foreign key column which will make join between worker and receipt table (Here let the column is supportId or something else). sum(count(columnName)) works fine, it will count how many customer is handled by a worker. Just follow the format.

Comment: The format doesn't work when I try, its giving errors for using both SUM(COUNT(columnName)) together

Comment: >>> no such column: b.SupportId get this error aswell , as supportId isn't in receipt table.

Answer (score 0):

use    GROUP BY to resolve your problem

Comment: Won't I have to use JOIN ?